# Woher kommt der Begriff Rambo?

Tags: etymology

Nach dem [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rambo) kommt der Begriff "Rambo" auch von der gleichnamigen Filmfigur "Rambo". Doch woher kommt dieser Begriff. Könnte es eine Ableitung von dem Begriff "Rammbock", im zerstörerischen Sinne sein?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Frage nach dem Ursprung des Namens *Rambo* hat der Autor, David Morrell, in einem Interview selbst beantwortet. Laut Wikipedia ist *„der Name [der [Filmfigur Rambo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rambo_(Film)#Herkunft_des_Namens_Rambo)] aus einem Rambo-Apfel (einer in den USA verbreiteten Apfelsorte) entstanden, den seine Frau nach Hause brachte, als er einen passenden Namen für seinen Protagonisten suchte“.*

Der [Rambo-Apfel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rambo_apple) wiederum soll nach einem Schweden, Peter Gunnarsson Rambo, benannt worden sein, der den Apfel in der amerikanischen Kolonie *New Sweden* kultivierte.